# Java VM Options: Set a -Djava.library.path relative to project folder

Tags: java, jvm

I would like to set the `-Djava.library.path` VM option to a specific folder. However, it is not relative to my project folder so that I could say for example:

```
-Djava.library.path=native\windows
```

(The folder *native* is in the project folder.)

Do you know if this is somehow possible to set it like above and not with `-Djava.library.path=C:\...`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually can set a relative path. For example if you start your program a specific folder, you can access libraries in a folder "libs" right next to it by setting the path to "../libs" e.g.

In my own project with native libraries I have this in my shell script:

```
-Djava.library.path=../../native/unix
```

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are asking how to refer to a relative directory on windows, or how to set this path without the `-Djava.library.path=...` parameter.  So, I will answer both.

To set a relative path, use:

```
-Djava.library.path=.\windows
```

To set this path on Windows without using -D, augment the PATH environment variable:

```
setenv PATH %PATH%;C:\path\to\folder
```

On Linux/Mac, set/augment the LD_LIBRARY_PATH with this folder location.